# javaFX: TableView's cellvalue is not enough to display in columns, it will be clipped, how to show a tip on such cell?

Tags: javafx, tableview

javaFX: TableView's cellvalue is not enough to display in columns, it will be clipped end of '...', how to show a tip on such cell?
I need a tip because sometimes i can't drag the colunm's head. So i can't see the whole content of the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below a subclass of TableCell is used to set the ToolTip for a cell. It does not distinguish between cells in which the text fits and those where the text is too large. It is used in the cell factory for the table column.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class SO extends Application {
    static class XCell extends TableCell<String, String> {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            this.setText(item);
            this.setTooltip(
                    (empty || item==null) ? null : new Tooltip(item));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Short",
                "This is quite long - almost very long");
        TableView<String> tv = new TableView<>(list);
        TableColumn<String, String> col = new TableColumn<>("Column");
        col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String,String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<String, String> param) {
                return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue());
            }
        });
        col.setMaxWidth(50);
        col.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<String,String>, TableCell<String,String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<String, String> call(TableColumn<String, String> param) {
                return new XCell();
            }
        });
        tv.getColumns().add(col);
        pane.getChildren().add(tv);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The result will look like this:

[image: Cell with tool tip]

Answer (score 0):

This should ACTUALLY solve your problem.

```
column.setCellFactory(col -> new TableCell<Object, String>()
    {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(final String item, final boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(item);
            TableColumn tableCol = (TableColumn) col;

            if (item != null && tableCol.getWidth() < new Text(item + "  ").getLayoutBounds().getWidth())
            {
                tooltipProperty().bind(Bindings.when(Bindings.or(emptyProperty(), itemProperty().isNull())).then((Tooltip) null).otherwise(new Tooltip(item)));
            } else
            {
                tooltipProperty().bind(Bindings.when(Bindings.or(emptyProperty(), itemProperty().isNull())).then((Tooltip) null).otherwise((Tooltip) null));
            }

        }
    });
```